# Firemonkey alternative to VCL ShortCut() function

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

What is firemonkey alternative to VCL Shortcut() function from Vcl.Menus?
Didn't find any neither in FMX.Menus or FMX.Platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no alternative in `FMX.Menus` but you can borrow the [`ShortCut`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.ShortCut) function from `Vcl.Menus` unit and add it into your code.

Comment: Mixing two different UI libraries in same project looks a bit ugly as for me. I prefer write my own ShortCut() then.

Comment: Agree with you, for me too, but in this case only the function would be linked. But in this case it's easy to *borrow* the function from VCL.

Comment: @TLama I wouldn't be too sure that only one function would be linked. Take a blank .dpr file and compile it. Executable size: 100KB. Add `Vcl.Menus` to the uses clause and compile it. Executable size: 6MB!

Comment: @David, uhm just vreified. Then I don't get what is being linked there since the classes are used from the FMX. I'll update the answer to not use the `Vcl.Menus` and writing the own `ShortCut` function.

Comment: Once you use a `Vcl.Menus`, most of the rest of the VCL is used by `Vcl.Menus` and the linker can't strip any of it because it can't see inside the .dfm files.